# CUDA: can __shfl delta be different between lanes?

Tags: c, cuda

According to the [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions), `__shfl()` intrinsics permit the exchange of a variable between threads. More specifically `__shfl_up()` and `__shfl_down()` (also `__shfl_xor()`) allow the exchange of a variable of a different lane. `unsigned int delta` is the second argument to these and specifies (positively or negatively) the `offset` lane id of the lane to exchange the variable from. I had always assumed this `delta` must be constant for all lanes in a warp. So, for example, one has to call like thus

```
val += __shfl_down(val, 3);
```

or

```
for (i = 1; i < warpSize / 2; i ++)
  val += __shfl_down(val, i);
```

however, I've just realized there is nothing explicitly stating that `delta` must be the same for all lanes (as long as all lanes are participating). Therefore, is the following `undefined` or fine

```
val += __shfl_down(val, threadIdx.x % warpSize);
```

This is just for example, and many of the lanes will add nothing as `delta` ["will not wrap around ... so effectively the upper `delta` lanes will remain unchanged.".](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-shuffle-functions) There is also nothing specifying that `delta` must be `>0`, `0` must just return the same as for out-of-range `delta`?

Further to this, is the documentation not contradicting itself here?

> Threads may only read data from another thread which is actively participating in the `__shfl()` command. If the target thread is inactive, the retrieved value is undefined.

So it is undefined for inactive threads, however ...

> All `__shfl()` intrinsics return the 4-byte word referenced by var from the source lane ID as an unsigned integer. If the source lane ID is out of range or the source thread has exited, the calling thread's own var is returned.

... which means that for inactive threads it returns the calling thread's own var. Which further means, that in the my example above, if `delta` is out-of-bounds it adds itself, not nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can __shfl delta be different between lanes?

Yes, the `delta` can be different between lanes.  This could be used, for example, to broadcast a 32-bit quantity from a single lane to other lanes (although this is not the only way to perform such a [broadcast](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-examples-broadcast)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void bcast() {
  int value = threadIdx.x;
  value = __shfl_up(value, threadIdx.x); // Get "value" from lane 0
  if (value) printf("Thread %u failed: %d\n", threadIdx.x, value);
}

int main() {
  bcast<<< 1, 32 >>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
```

Regarding your question about `delta` values, (note that the [function prototypes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synopsis) for `__shfl_up` and `__shfl_down` insist that `delta` is an `unsigned int` quantity, so it can't be negative),   the question about a `delta` value of `0` is not quite clear to me.  That would reference the origination lane, which by definition cannot be out-of-range or inactive.  So, yes,  a zero index value would return the origination lane value, just as an out-of-range index would.

Regarding your last question, an out-of bounds computed source lane ID is not the same thing as an in-bounds computed source lane ID that happens to reference an inactive thread.  In the former case, the threads own shuffle variable is returned.  In the latter case, the returned value is undefined.

Computation of the source lane ID for `delta` values greater than 31 may also have some additional complexity.  Casually, such computations would appear to be always out-of-bounds (but the actual behavior may be somewhat more complicated).   I'm not sure the documentation clearly touches on this, and I'm not sure this is the crux of any of your questions.